# GDPR - client and server side data

Tags: gdpr

I am trying to figure out if with the following scenario, a user can still be identified somehow and if it follows GDPR rules.

The scenario is the following:

A user visits a page and a unique `user_id` is generated which is stored in both the browser cookies as well as in the database.

The unique `user_id` in the browser cookies has an expiration date, let's say 1 year.

1 year later the unique `user_id` in the browser cookies expires, but that same `user_id` exists still in the database.

Is it still considered personal information or a way to identify the user if the `user_id` only exists in the database and not in the browser cookies anymore ?

Taking into account that no other personal information are stored in the database, such as name, email etc.

Comment: Can someone else get assigned the same ID from the site after 1 year passed since someone was there or is ti tied to a login?=

Comment: it is not tied to a log in but also it is not possible somebody else to get that same id.  Basically the id that is generated is a UUID which guarantees uniqueness

Comment: Then you got your answer.

Comment: that unique user_id can be linked to a user as long as the user_id exists in both the browser and the database. Once it is deleted from the browser cookies, there is no way you can link the user_id you have in the database to anything.

Comment: Then why have it? Just delete it after a year?

Comment: @nvoigt the typical use case is that you still want to have session- and user based metrics, even if they are not connected to a specific user. However this creates essentially a user profile, which might be connected back to a specific person, which presumably makes it a GDPR issue (pseudonymisation does not change anything GDPR-wise and anonymization would break the use case). Typically anything that allows to build profiles would count as personal data, but it would be hard to point to a specific sentence in the GDPR that unambigously says that.

Answer (score 3):

The GDPR only applies to personal information and by extent to information that can be linked to personal information.

And IP address or telephone number for example, while a rather meaningless somewhat random number just assigned to people to make them uniquely identifiable, are protected because *somewhere* there is a database tying those unique but meaningless numbers to a person. Probably the person that pays for it, with all their private data.

At face value, your unique identifier is not. If you never connect any other data with it, then it is not subject to the GDPR. It's just a random number you gave out.

That said, if you never connect any other data to it, it also is absolutely pointless and a waste of bytes, so I doubt that this question and answer in isolation is of any help in the real world.

So the real question is, what *other data* are you going to connect to it, and is it legal to do so. I cannot answer this. You will have to make that decision on a case-by-case basis.

For example, you could have someone pick a color scheme and save it with your random id. The selection of "green with stripes or yellow with dots" is not personal information either. But if you save someone's IP with it, or maybe their name or timestamps of activity, that would be another topic.

Comment: The random identifier still makes it possible to distinguish different persons, even though we can't tie an identifier back to a person. This may count as identification for GDPR purposes, since the definition of identification in Recital 26 GDPR mentions "singling out" as an example. I strongly suspect that such pseudonyms and associated data are still personal data, but that they benefit from the compliance simplifications in Art 11 GDPR (greatly restricted data subject rights).

Answer (score 2):

### Everything attached to the `user_id` is personal data

> (1) ‘personal data’ means any information relating to an identified or identifiable natural person (‘data subject’); an identifiable natural person is one who can be identified, directly or indirectly, in particular by reference to an identifier such as a name, **an Identification number**, location data, an online identifier or to one or more factors specific to the physical, physiological, genetic, mental, economic, cultural or social identity of that natural person;

GDPR Article 4

With respect to @nvoight - the following is wrong:

> For example, you could have someone pick a color scheme and save it with your random id. The selection of "green with stripes or yellow with dots" is not personal information either.

The fact that I chose "green with stripes or yellow with dots" is personal information. If you attach it to a `user_id`, it’s subject to the GDPR regardless of where it’s stored. If you just count how many people made those choices, it isn’t.

For a slightly more practical concept - the fact that I went to a particular football match is personal information, the fact that 23,453 people went, isn’t. If you store the first fact, you need to comply with the GDPR.

Comment: How the hell is the user in the OP's scenario _identifiable_? Quite often it won't even be a human.

Comment: The same way @Greendrake identifies you

Comment: I am identifiable because my ID is not randomly generated, it actually matches my surname. Not so in the question.

Comment: "the fact that **I** went" yes, that is identifiable, because of the "**I**". I think you are putting too much thought into the fact they named their field "user_id". The information "3b47c4ff-543f-46fb-9c56-8b7374ba7482 went to see Tottenham vs Munich" is not, if you don't save anything else about "3b47c4ff-543f-46fb-9c56-8b7374ba7482". The more information you stick to it, the more of a profile it may become and at some point it might be identifiable, but my example was basically: "this instance of my program is running in darkmode", which is about as neutral as you can get.

Comment: If that simple decision where PII, nobody here would be able to click any button, ever.